# seekbar thumb / background scale (size) change

Tags: android

I have a question about a `seekbar`.
Everything works perfect, but I have a Problem with the background and the thumb.
I can add a background with a special size of the thumb. If I change the size of the seekbar the background size will change identical to the seekbar size but
the thumb keeps the original size. (I know that I can change the width and the height of the thumb with the attributes.)

Now the question: Is there a way that the thumb changes automatically the size when I change the seekbar size inside the `activity_main` like the background.
I need this for a special LED Bar.

Comment: not clearly understood for me

Answer (score 0):

I hope this pictures will help to understand it

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipLWr.png)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUomu.png)

The frame is the Background of the seekbar. If i change the size the frame size will be changed automatically. The thumb will not changed